# How to connect django local with postgress in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

How to connect live Heroku postgress with my local server. Is there is any way to back up the Heroku database?

How is a database connection in Heroku production done?

Here's is my **local.py**

```
import dj_database_url
from .base import *

ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost:8000'] 
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')  
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS.extend([
    'collectfast',
])
INSTALLED_APPS.extend([
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # 'djcelery',

])

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
print(DATABASE_URL)

# AWS and S3  settings
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'jagah-production'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True

# Static files settings
#STATICFILES_STORAGE = ''
#STATIC_S3_PATH = 'static'
#STATIC_ROOT = '/%s/' % STATIC_S3_PATH
#STATIC_URL = '' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress):

> In addition to being available to the Heroku runtime, Heroku Postgres
>   databases can be accessed directly by clients running on your local
>   computer or elsewhere.
>
> > All connections require SSL: sslmode=require.
>
> You can retrieve the PG connection string in one of two ways. heroku
>   pg:credentials is discussed above:
>
> ```
> $ heroku pg:credentials DATABASE Connection info string:   
> "dbname=dee932clc3mg8h host=ec2-123-73-145-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com
> port=6212 user=user3121 password=98kd8a9 sslmode=require" Also, the
> ```
>
> connection string is exposed as a config var for your app:
>
> ```
> $ heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL:
> postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398
> ```